# wordpress &quot added after import post

Tags: import, htmlspecialchars-decode

After I import posts from old site to new one I see added encoded html characters, such as  `&quot;` or `it's` is escaped to `it\'s`.

For example exported content;

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="200" scrolling="no" src="https:
```

is imported as:

```
<iframe frameborder="\&quot;0\&quot;" scrolling="\&quot;no\&quot;" src="\&quot;https:
```

I tried some solutions found on other forum posts:

- disabling SEO plugins
- setting force_filtered_html_on_import to false

  add_filter( 'force_filtered_html_on_import', '__return_false' );
- comparing 'DB_CHARSET' in wp-config

Nothing works for me.

---

For export I use default Wordpress export. For import Wordpress Importer plugin

---

Update
I see that this isssue is not related to importer only, but also shows for any pages generated by plugins.

Comment: How are you exporting and importing the posts? Seems important but you don't mention it for some reason.

Comment: For export I use default Wordpress export. For import Wordpress Importer plugin